# Proof that no non-trivial integer solution exists?

Tags: systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

The equation system

$$2ab+2ac+2bc=4a+4b+4c$$

$$2ab+2ac+2bc=abc$$

In short $$2ab+2ac+2bc=4a+4b+4c=abc$$

has, according to Wolfram Alpha, only the trivial integer solution $a=b=c=0$. I would like to prove this. My approach (not sure whether it is helpful) is using the equation $$(a-2)(b-2)(c-2)=abc-2ab-2ac-2bc+4a+4b+4c-8$$ which simplifies to $$(a-2)(b-2)(c-2)=4(a+b+c-2)$$ if we have $2ab+2ac+2bc=abc$, but I do not see how can I make progress.

Motivation : The circumference and the area of a rectangular with sides $a$ and $b$, if we do not consider units has the same value than the area , when $$2a+2b=ab$$ holds. The only solutions in positive integers are $(3,6)$ $(4,4)$ , $(6,3)$, so besides the square with length $4$ only the rectangular with sides $3$ and $6$ has the property that area and length are equal in the described sense.

I wanted to extend this to a cuboid with lengths $a,b,c$ , for which the sum of the lengths of the edges ($4a+4b+4c$) is equal to the surface ($2ab+2ac+2bc$) and the volume ($abc$).

The desired proof would show that no integer cuboid with this proprty exists.

Comment: I'd try the cubic equation having $a,b,c$ as roots.

Answer (score 2):

One has $$(ab+bc+ca)^2 = a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + 2abc(a+b+c) = a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 + 2(2ab+2bc+2ca)(\frac{1}{2}(ab+bc+ca))$$
Then $$a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 = -(ab+bc+ca)^2$$

So, one gets $ab=bc=ca=ab+bc+ca=0$,or $a=b=c=0$.

EDIT: i make it clear at the last step as @peter's comment:
One gets from $ab=bc=ca=0$ that $a=b=0$, but note that $c=a+b+c=\frac{1}{2}(ab+bc+ca)=0$.

Comment: Nice proof, only a slight remark : The last equation $ab=bc=ca=0$ would allow $a=b=0$ and $c\ne 0$ (and analogue the two other possibilities). But the equation $2ab+2bc+2ca=4a+4b+4c$ gives immediately $c=0$. If you add this detail, I will accept the answer (+1)